# Using AsyncResult when http connection cannot stay open for long

Tags: future, ejb-3.1, java-ee-7, servlet-3.0

Due to an old reverse proxy of the customer (thread-per-connection model), I cannot leave client connections open for long.

Let's say that a browser request results in calling an Asynchronous EJB method which takes 3 minutes to be processed. Can I still utilize the returned `Future`? Should I store it somewhere so that it is accessible across different requests?

What would be a good practice to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't sound good to let the request wait for 3 minutes. You can better use signalr kind of something in which case you can call the client from server.